# Trying to render an array of items with the drupal_add_html_head function

Tags: 7, theming

I have a `preprocess_html` function that gets an array of google fonts and adds them as an html class. I have it partially working but if say I have three fonts, only the last one gets into `<html class="">` element. Here is what I have so far:

```
if ($families) {
   foreach ($families as $fontString) {
   $fontclass = preg_replace('/[^\d\w]+/', '-', strtolower($fontString));

   $element = array(
     '#tag' => 'html',
     '#attributes' => array(
     'class' => $fontclass,
    ),
   );
   drupal_add_html_head($element, 'google_fonts');
  }
}
```

In the example above, I have these fonts in my site:

- Montserrat
- Actor
- Pathway Gothic One

... but only the last one renders in my html class as:

```
<html class="pathway-gothic-one-regular">
```

If I do a dsm within my function:

```
dsm(drupal_get_html_head());
```

I see all three fonts print out in separate boxes as

```
<html class="actor-regular" />
<html class="montserrat-regular" />
<html class="pathway-gothic-one-regular" />
```

so I think I am not getting something right here.

Note, if I change my code to a body class array, it works as expected. e.g.

```
   if ($families) {
          foreach ($families as $fontString) {
            $vars['classes_array'][] = preg_replace('/[^\d\w]+/', '-', strtolower($fontString));
          }
        }
```

yields:

```
<body class="actor-regular montserrat-regular pathway-gothic-one-regular">
```

From a build standpoint, I'd like to keep these classes one level higher than body so that's why I'd like them to be in `<html class="">`.

Comment: Try moving the $element = array(...) to above the  foreach with no class, then just target the class inside the foreach: ie. $element['#attributes']['class'][] = $fontclass. And move the drupal_add_html_head out of the foreach to the bottom

Comment: Brilliant, that works, thanks. You should add that as an answer and I will mark it as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ($families) {
    $element = array(
        '#tag' => 'html',
    );
    foreach ($families as $fontString) {
        $fontclass = preg_replace('/[^\d\w]+/', '-', strtolower($fontString));
        $element['#attributes'][class'][] = $fontclass;
    }
    drupal_add_html_head($element, 'google_fonts');
}
```